# Problem getting mod_wsgi running with apache

Tags: python, django, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

Not had any problems implementing this set up before, got a new server set up at home and wanted to work on some django projects.

Im using virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper, mod_wsgi module seems to be installed correctly.  here is the vhost im using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName local.projectname.com
        ServerAlias local.projectname.co.uk

        WSGIDaemonProcess site-dev1 user=mike group=mike threads=20 python-path=/home/mike/envs/projectenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site-dev1
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mike/Sites/path/project/django.wsgi

        <Directory /home/mike/Sites/path/project>
                Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Allow cross domain @font-face styles for Firefox
        <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
                <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
                </IfModule>
        </FilesMatch>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When try to navigate to the project i get 500 internal server error, heres the out put from the apache error logs

```
[Sun Jul 24 08:46:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 24 08:46:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/mike/Sites/outsideline/queenonline/queenonline.wsgi", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Jul 24 08:46:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[Sun Jul 24 08:46:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

I can import from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler in shell with out any errors, As i understand it the process and group of the WSGIdaemon should be the user and group owners of the files, i have also set my apache user and group to run as mike:mike to see if that would work

Im totally out of ideas now so if anyone can shed some light on this i will be eternally grateful!

Comment: Anyone got any ideas "

Comment: When you have imported Django in the shell, what do you get for 'django.__file__'. This will tell you location of where Django is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PYTHONPATH

To debug this problem you can output logging output from your .wsgi script to a file using a logger (Python logger). PYTHONPATH can be read inside Python using sys.path

```
  import sys
  log = open("/tmp/log.txt", "wt") # ghetto logging
  print >> log, sys.path # you'll see what you have PYTHONPATH when running the script
```

Then you can check if Python can actually open the file

```
  import sys
  log = open("/tmp/log.txt", "wt") # ghetto logging
  try:
      f = open("/path/to/django/__init__.py", "rt")
  exception Exception, e:
      print >> log, str(e)
```